# How to process the data in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please help to solve next task. I have an array

```
var results = [
    ['usd','sell',1000],
    ['usd','sell',1200],
    ['usd','buy',3000],
    ['eur','sell',2000],
    ['eur','buy',1000]
];
```

I need to get output with total sum of sell and buy for each currency.

```
{ 
  {currency: 'usd', sell:2200, buy:3000}, 
  {currency: 'eur', sell:2000, buy:1000} 
}
```

additional condition: we don't know exact currency, today it's usd and euro and tomorrow we can receive array with new currency.

update. thanks to everybody for the tips and advise. I had problem with additional condition, but now it's done. Here is my solution:

```
var inputs = [         // results
    ['usd','sell',1000],
    ['usd','sell',1200],
    ['eur','buy',3000],
    ['uah','sell',2000],
    ['uah','buy',1000]
];

var totalOrders = {};

for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    var order = inputs[i];

    var currencyCode = order[0];
    var operation = order[1];
    var volume = order[2];

    if(!totalOrders[currencyCode]){
        totalOrders[currencyCode]={buy:0, sell:0}
    }
    totalOrders[currencyCode][operation] += volume;

}
console.log(totalOrders);
```

Comment: What have you tried? You'll get a much better response if you show some effort.

Comment: It's not un common to ask a question seeking the answer James, we can't assume he hasn't tried anything, and also can't assume that he has the skill set to know what to try... everyone starts from somewhere!

Comment: @Jubair "*we can't assume he hasn't tried anything*" This is exactly the problem -- knowing *what* the OP has tried allows answers to be targeted to the OP's level of understanding. We don't know if the OP doesn't understand how to access the elements of an array with `[ ]` syntax, or doesn't understand `for` loops, etc. We are not trying to punish the user for not trying anything, but rather we are trying to improve the quality of the question (and thereby improve the quality of resulting answers) by learning what sub-problem is most difficult for the OP.

Comment: And for that reason, I'd say comment but not down vote, unless you spend the effort to remove your down vote when the question is fixed (many don't).

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop will do, propped by a lookup-table:

```
var input = …; // your "results"

var currencies = {},
    result = [];
for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    var c = input[i][0];
    if (c in currencies)
        var o = currencies[c];
    else {
        var o = {currency:c, sell:0, buy:0};
        result.push(currencyIndex[c] = o);
    }
    o[input[i][1]] += input[i][2];
}
return result;
```